# Most Simple way to programatically delete textboxes in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a dictionary of text boxes I'm using for my program.  When changing options I want the boxes to be deleted so that new ones can be made for the next page.

```
    public static bool command0 () {
        foreach (TextBox tBox in Globals.inputBoxes)
            tBox = null;
        return true;
    }
```

that returns this error

```
Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,System.Windows.Forms.TextBox>' to 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' (CS0030) - C:\Users\e309706\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\simulator 3\simulator 3\Globals.cs:73,4
```

Is there a simple and correct way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Side note: " correct way to do what I'm trying to do" likely does not include any kind of "globals" nor removing textboxes... but since you have not actually said what you are trying to do you'll get just literal solutions to your syntax error.

Comment: My answer is to solve the exception that you're receiving. Actually removing them from the form should be easier now that you're able to actually access the text boxes. If you still can't figure that out, that becomes a separate question.

Comment: I didn't realize I had a syntax error, so literal corrections are useful.  What more information do you think I should have given?  I thought I was clear, I want to remove all of the textboxes in my dictionary.  The name globals is probably misleading, globals is just a static class with common data under a single namespace, is that something I shouldn't do?

Comment: If you want to remove all of your textboxes in the dictionary you might want to use dictionary.Clear()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Globals.inputBoxes` is a dictionary, so they will iterate over the key value pairs. Adjust your code to this:

```
// This kvp variable is what your exception is saying was wrong.
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, TextBox> kvp in Globals.inputBoxes)
{
    Textbox txt = kvp.Value;
    // Do what you need to with the txt object now
}
```

**EDIT**

There is also another way to do this, as several people have suggested:

```
foreach (TextBox txtin Globals.inputBoxes.Values)
{
    // Do what you need to with the txt object now
}
```

The thing about this additional method is that a lot of the time, you could also want to use the key from the dictionary within your loop. Iterating just the values will not allow you access to that without accessing the dictionary again.

Comment: ... or enumerate the `Values` property.

Comment: Or "foreach (TextBox textBox in Globals.inputBoxes.Values)"

Comment: Also, OP might want to use `Clear` since there is no `Delete` method. Or he wants to remove them from the form, but then we have not enough informations.

Comment: Thanks, @TimSchmelter. That `Delete` was just a "dummy" method to call. I updated to remove a method that doesn't exist.